# Does React has element like <template/> in vue which is only for wrapping stuffs but not has true effect on html's structure?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, render

I have a problem on React conditional rendering these days. As we all know, when we use conditional rendering to determine whether some elements will be rendered or not.We have to wrap these elements with `<div/>` or something else to make sure each condition only returns one object. But obviously the wrapper do have some effects on html structure which is not good for us especially when we are making a list or something else.

So my question is that how to use conditional rendering but don't have any structural effects on html? Does React has something similar with `<template/>` in Vue or there is some other ways to solve this problem?

Thank you all! :)

```
          <Row>
             {customerClass === '6' ? (
                <div>
                  <Col span="8">
                    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                      {getFieldDecorator('businessUnitName', {
                        rules: [
                          { required: true, message: '' },
                          {
                            validator: this.checkBusinessUnitName,
                          },
                        ],
                      })(<Input placeholder="" />)}
                    </FormItem>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span="8">
                    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                      {getFieldDecorator('businessUnitAddress', {
                        rules: [{ required: true, message: '' }],
                      })(<Cascader options={storage.get('addressData')} placeholder="" showSearch />)}
                    </FormItem>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span="8">
                    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                      {getFieldDecorator('businessUnitAdd', {
                        rules: [
                          { required: true, message: '' },
                          { whitespace: true, message: '' },
                          {
                            validator: this.checkBusinessUnitAdd,
                          },
                        ],
                      })(<Input placeholder="" />)}
                    </FormItem>
                  </Col>
                </div>
              ) : null}
              {['1', '2', '3', '4'].includes(customerClass) ? (
                <Col span="8">
                  <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                    {getFieldDecorator('shareholdingRatio', {
                      rules: [
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: '',
                        },
                        {
                          validator: this.checkShareholding,
                        },
                      ],
                    })(<Input placeholder="" addonAfter="%" />)}
                  </FormItem>
                </Col>
              ) : null}
              {['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].includes(customerClass) ? (
                <Col span="8">
                  <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                    {getFieldDecorator('businessLicenceCode', {
                      rules: [
                        { required: true, message: '' },
                        { whitespace: true, message: '' },
                        { len: 18, message: '' },
                      ],
                    })(<Input placeholder="" />)}
                  </FormItem>
                </Col>
              ) : null}
              {['1', '2', '3', '4'].includes(customerClass) ? (
                <div>
                  <Col span="8">
                    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                      {getFieldDecorator('registeredCapital', {
                        rules: [
                          {
                            required: true,
                            message: '',
                          },
                          {
                            // validator: this.checkCapital,
                            pattern: REG_UPTO_TEN_CHAR,
                            message: '',
                          },
                        ],
                      })(<Input placeholder="" addonAfter="" />)}
                    </FormItem>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span="8">
                    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                      {getFieldDecorator('paiclUpCapital', {
                        rules: [
                          {
                            required: true,
                            message: '',
                          },
                          {
                            // validator: this.checkCapital,
                            pattern: REG_UPTO_TEN_CHAR,
                            message: '',
                          },
                        ],
                      })(<Input placeholder="" addonAfter="" />)}
                    </FormItem>
                  </Col>
                </div>
              ) : null}
              {['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'].includes(customerClass) ? (
                <Col span="8">
                  <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="">
                    {getFieldDecorator('employeesNum', {
                      rules: [{ required: true, message: '' }],
                    })(<Input placeholder="" />)}
                  </FormItem>
                </Col>
              ) : null}
            </Row>
```

I picked some code from my personal project which uses Ant Design to be the UI lib.When I use `<div/>` to do the wrap stuff on contional rendering, those `<Col>` elements looks like a mess for they are not in order on the page.Can you help me with this?

Comment: hey mate, hoping I'm understanding correctly - are you just looking for fragments: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html? If that looks like it let me know and I'll post a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Chris God! I was so thoughtless about this question...I should have read the React doc several times before asking this...But sincerely thank you very much! : D

Comment: haha no worries mate - the docs are pretty long and I think we've all been there :p

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably looking for Fragments. These will let you return multiple elements without having to wrap them in a div etc:

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You can also use empty angled brackets as shorthand for these:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just read this from react docs.But I forgot that my react version is v15.4,which hasn't been update for a long time for the tedious migration from v15 to v16.When I use React.Fragment to do the wrap,some part of code works perfect while others have problems.In my thought the Fragment element should have no fluence to the project.So these errors seems very weird to me.Do you have any recommend about solving this problem?T_T

Comment: hey mate, you'd have to tell us what errors you're getting - not much to go off there.